# Do subordinating conjunctions subordinate clauses with verbs only?

Tags: conjunctions, clauses

> 1. **While** in Rome, John took a lot of pictures.
> 2. **While** he was in Rome, John took a lot of pictures.
> 3. **Although** on vacation, John calls the office often.
> 4. **Although** he is on vacation, John calls the office often.
> 5. Many people have a disinclination to recognize the weakness of their
>      analytical skills **while** willing to admit their lack of computer skills
>      or other technical skills.
> 6. Many people have a disinclination to admit fault **while** recognizing
>      that they can’t possibly be in the right all the time.

Both While and Although are subordinating conjunctions, I am confused whether they should be followed by a full clause (with verb) or not.

Which one of the above examples are incorrect? I have seen many "while +ing," modifiers whereas Although **must** be followed by a clause which has a subject and a verb. Is that correct?

Which subordinating conjunctions (as in ON A WHITE BUS mnemonic) must be followed by a clause with verbs and which ones are more flexible?

Excuse my English - not a native speaker.

Comment: All clauses have verbs. Sometimes the verbs are all predictable auxiliaries, however, and get deleted. Like _he is/was_ in the odd-numbered versions. This is pretty normal for adverbial clauses; they decay into participial and prepositional phrases pretty easily.

Comment: I think the culprit is *while*: it presupposes an ongoing activity.

Comment: #5,#6 while is in contrasting function

Comment: @John Lawler 'Many people have a disinclination to admit fault while they are recognizing that they can’t possibly be in the right all the time' sounds far less natural than 'Many people have a disinclination to admit fault, while they recognize that they can’t possibly be in the right all the time.' Is there an explanation of a "reduction to a participial 'phrase' " (I'm in the 'clause' school) here?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think the "unnaturalness" is a function of placement; "while they are" seems to modify the preceding predicate rather than the subject. *Many people, while recognizing ..., have a disinclination ... * works just fine for me.

Comment: @StoneyB/ And to me. I'm wondering about the mechanics of the said (and likely) reduction ('Many people have a disinclination to admit fault, while they recognize that they can’t possibly be in the right all the time.' ==?==> 'Many people have a disinclination to admit fault while recognizing that they can’t possibly be in the right all the time.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is my initial attempt to answer your final question.

```
Y = can be reduced
N = can't be reduced
? = some people may allow a reduced form
S = some reductions but not others seem allowable
Q = would seem to be reducible, but not by simple elision of a form of be
```

**only if** (Y)

> - only if he is taking his tablets
> - only if taking his tablets

**now that** (N)

> - now that he is taking his tablets
> - <strike>now that taking his tablets</strike>

**after** (Q)

> - after he is taking his tablets
> - after taking his tablets

**although** (Y)

> - although he is taking his tablets
> - although taking his tablets

**as** (N)

> - as he is taking his tablets
> - <strike>as taking his tablets</strike>

**when** (Y)

> - when he is taking his tablets
> - when taking his tablets

**whereas** (N)

> - whereas he is taking his tablets
> - <strike>whereas taking his tablets</strike>

**while** (Y/S)

> - while he is taking his tablets
> - while taking his tablets

**whenever** (?)

> - whenever he is taking his tablets
> - whenever taking his tablets

**wherever** (S)

> - wherever he is taking his tablets
> - wherever taking his tablets

**whether or not** (S)

> - whether or not he is taking his tablets
> - whether or not taking his tablets

**in case** (N)

> - in case he is taking his tablets
> - <strike>in case taking his tablets</strike>

**if** (S)

> - if he is taking his tablets
> - if taking his tablets

**though** (Y)

> - though he is taking his tablets
> - though taking his tablets

**even though** (Y)

> - even though he is taking his tablets
> - even though taking his tablets

**even if** (Y)

> - even if he is taking his tablets
> - even if taking his tablets

**before** (Q)

> - before he is taking his tablets
> - before taking his tablets

**because** (N)

> - because he is taking his tablets
> - <strike>because taking his tablets</strike>

**until** (Q)

> - until he is taking his tablets
> - until taking his tablets

**unless** (Y)

> - unless he is taking his tablets
> - unless taking his tablets

**since** (Q)

> - since he is taking his tablets
> - since taking his tablets

**so [that]** (N)

> - so [that] he is taking his tablets
> - <strike>so [that] taking his tablets</strike>

This is, as I say, an attempt. Others may find it needs correcting / adjusting.

Comment: It's a good start, anyway. Look over the self-confessed "Deletions" (pp 8-10) [in this list](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/Preliminarybufattenedlistoftransformations.pdf) for further possibilities. Plus, here's another partial [list of "subordinating conjunctions"](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/subordinatingconjunctions.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

Whilst accepting what John Lawler says, I can't agree with your suggestion re 'although'.

'Although ill, he went to work' or

'Although 90 years old, he runs marathons',

are perfectly everyday grammatical expressions.

Comment: I'd say 'though' is the usual choice here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes 'though' or 'although' both work here.